Как правильно работать с JobQueue в python telegram bot
Мне нужно чтобы бот раз месяц присылал сообщение, но видимо я что-то упускаю, потому что бот ничего не присылает в нужное время. Подскажите пожалуйста.
async def monthly_task(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    total_month_expenses = await expense.get_current_month_expenses() # тут строка
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=context.job.chat_id, text=total_month_expenses)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(TELEGRAM_TOKEN).build()

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start) # просто приветсвие
    application.add_handler(start_handler)

    month_job = application.job_queue
    month_job.run_monthly(monthly_task, when=datetime.time(hour=12, minute=50, second=0), day=4)


